# How do I remove my ignored tags questions from my Stack Overflow homepage?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ignored-tags

Hi guys,

I know this is not good to do it, but I need to focus on minimum tags in this website  as a start , and I can add any tags later on, so my question is:

how can I remove ignored tags questions from my stackoverflow homepage questions?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Click your username, go to "prefs" click `Hide Ignored Tags`