# Provide a way to exclude tags from display

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, tag-watching

I wish it were possible to exclude questions from [the front page's *interesting* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) based on tags (the opposite of *favorite tags*). For example, I don't own an iPhone, a Mac or an Android device, and I will not develop for, buy nor use any of them for a few years at least. So, I don't want questions tagged [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) or [android](/questions/tagged/android) to appear on my "interesting" tab (because they **are not** interesting to me).

Comment: I feel like this was asked a really long time ago and declined; searching for link

Comment: even if it somewhen was posted here, maybe it would be a good idea to renew it make it actual? =)

Comment: Just to check, but isn't this what the Ignored Tags feature is for? [You can also configure it to hide those instead of simply greying them out.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50582/how-do-i-remove-my-ignored-tags-questions-from-my-stack-overflow-homepage)

Comment: Oh that's right, you can actually hide ignored tags altogether now. Well, alrighty, then.

Comment: @Popular You might've been thinking about either the requests to not fetch ignored items at all (declined) or the requests to *only* fetch interesting items (not yet declined but no motion either).

Comment: @CRags sure, but a) this was asked earlier; b) this question goes about tags, not about SE sites in the feed.

Comment: Thanks deleted the wrong tag. Maybe related questions?

Comment: @CRags i believe, they are not related =) This question is specific to the question feed, while that question is related to news feed =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't this the same thing as ignoring a tag?

[image]

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/

**You can do this in your *User page → prefs* tab.**

Comment: +1 for using a 0 (zero) instead of an O (oooooooohhhhhhh). :)

Comment: Note that this seems to work only on SE browser version and only in desktop mode, also the UI is different on scifi SE and there appears to be no convenient way to do it from SE app on Android.